# SharePoint Remote Event Receivers

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, synchronization

I was wondering what is the behavior of synchronous event receivers when multiple items are added at a same time? in the following blog it is mentioned that "synchronous event handlers have a blocking nature because they run on the same thread that is processing the event action."

Does that mean, if i add multiple items, then the logic will be executed for one item at a time and not concurrently?

http://www.splessons.com/lesson/sharepoint-synchronous-and-asynchronous-event-receivers/

Comment: Your question title references remote event receivers while your question text and the link seem to refer to on-premises event receivers. Those are different things. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Remote Event Receivers

Answer (score 0):

A Remote Event Receiver is just a web endpoint. It takes requests and makes responses. It can handle multiple requests just like a normal website can handle multiple requests.